# Getting information form json encode

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <button onclick="cart(0)"> hi </button>
            <p id="disp"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**jsfile.js**

```
function cart(id1)
{

    var id=id1;
    //alert("enterd "+id);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML ="hi";
    if (window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery is available.

    // Print the jQuery version, e.g. "1.0.0":
    //alert(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
        $.ajax({
        url:"add.php ",
        type:"POST",

        data:{
          item_id: id,
        },
        success:function(response) {

         document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML =response.value1;
       },
       error:function(){
        alert("error");
       }

      });

}
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['item_id'])){
    //if(count($_POST)>0)
        echo json_encode(array("value1" => "hello", "value2" => "hi"));

    }
?>
```

am collection the informaton from add.php to jsfile.js ... I am not able to get information from the json array.. I am trying to get information by respnse.value1. But it returns me undefined.. what might be the error??

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse the JSON before using it. Change your success function to this -

```
success:function(response) {
     var res = JSON.parse(response);
     document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = res.value1;
},
```